# Left Join entre dos tablas en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Intento hacer lo siguiente:

```
  SELECT a.id_serie, a.serie_num, IFNULL(d.total,0)

  FROM ( SUBCONSULTA ) d

  LEFT
  JOIN fact_contabilidad a
    ON a.id_serie = d.id_serie
    AND a.serie_num = d.serie_num
```

- La subconsulta es una consulta muy muy extensa de varios selects anidados donde hay muchas tablas involucradas y no la muestro para que quede más claro, dejo un extracto de la subconsulta.

> ```
> id_serie | serie_num | nombre   | total
> 2508     | 1         | Cliente1 | 20€
> 2508     | 2         | Cliente1 | 10€
> 2508     | 4         | Cliente2 | 20€
> ```

Ahora bien, quiero hacer un left join entre esa consulta anterior y una tabla donde se encuentra todas las series, como la siguiente:

> ```
> id_serie | serie_num | nombre  
> 2508     | 1         | Cliente1         
> 2508     | 2         | Cliente1      
> 2508     | 3         | Cliente2
> 2508     | 4         | Cliente2
> ```

- La serie_num = 3 no aparece en la anterior.

Y el resultado debería ser el siguiente:

> ```
> id_serie | serie_num | nombre   | total
> 2508     | 1         | Cliente1 | 20€
> 2508     | 2         | Cliente1 | 10€
> 2508     | 3         | Cliente1 | 0€
> 2508     | 4         | Cliente2 | 20€
> ```

Quiero listar todas las series y si en la subconsulta no existe una línea, que la marque con 0€.

¿Es posible? Estoy intentándolo pero no se donde fallo.

Comment: Si quieres que aparezca la serie_num = 3, que solo está en la tabla de la derecha, debería ser un right join o un full join ¿no?

Comment: No quiero que aparezca sólo la 3, fíjate bien en el resultado que quiero que aparezca. Deben salir todas (incluyendo la 3 que no está en la subconsulta).

Comment: Si quieres que salgan todas, entre ellas la 3, no puedes hacer un left join, porque en la tabla de la izquierda, que es por la que estás uniendo, no aparece la 3. En el ejemplo que pones funcionaría un full join o un right join, deberías mirar cuál quieres de los dos, pensando en otros ejemplos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para que el resultado del "join" tenga una fila por cada fila de la tabla "fact_contabilidad", debes poner esta tabla antes del `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.id_serie, a.serie_num, IFNULL(d.total, '0€')
FROM fact_contabilidad a
LEFT JOIN ( SUBCONSULTA ) d
    ON a.id_serie = d.id_serie
    AND a.serie_num = d.serie_num
```

Con la función `IFNULL()` puedes pasar un valor por defecto en caso de que no haya una fila en la tabla "d" con la que hacer el join.

Comment: Error 500 despues de 3 minutos, no se puede procesar la petición. La subconsulta de manera independiente tarda 1 segundo en ejecutarse.

Comment: Puedes probar la consulta en phpmyadmin o algo? No sé por qué te puede estar tardando tanto, pero la idea principal es que si quieres añadirle algo a cada fila de fact_contabilidad, la debes poner antes del `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Vale, le he metido unas condiciones al final y ya va perfecto, gracias, me sirve.